# How to skip a token in java, Scanner class

Tags: java, token, java.util.scanner

I have searched Stack Overflow for an understandable solution to my problem but I have not found one. This method is supposed to take a text file and put the information in an Array of Objects.

The text file is formatted as follows:

1#Mr Jhon Doe#Taxi#34.7
3#Mrs Jackson Tammy#Phone#20.5

The general format is

GuestNumber#GuestName#Reason#Cost (int String String double)

The method puts the information into an array of objects, arrItems, of the ExtraItems class which keeps track of additional costs bought by a guest who is identified by their guest number.

The class variables for the Guest class are Guest Number, Reason, Cost. I cannot find a way to skip the Guest Name when creating instances of the class, and I keep getting errors. I have tried the .skip() method and got a NoSuchElementException, and I have tried removing the guest's name and making a new Scanner instance for the line from the text file, and I got a InputMismatchExpression. I have attached my code below which does not account for the extra token.

```
public TestExtraItem(String textFile)
{
    try
    {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(textFile));
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine() && counter < 100)
        {

            String line = inputStream.nextLine();
            Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("#");
            arrItems[counter] = new ExtraItem(lineReader.nextInt(), lineReader.next(), lineReader.nextDouble());
            lineReader.close();
            counter++;

        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

and my attempt at solving it`

```
public TestExtraItem(String textFile)
{
    try
    {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(textFile));
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine() && counter < 100)
        {

            String line = inputStream.nextLine();
            Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(line).skip("Mr").useDelimiter("#");
            arrItems[counter] = new ExtraItem(lineReader.nextInt(), lineReader.next(), lineReader.nextDouble());
            lineReader.close();
            counter++;

        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

I had other attempts but this was the one I thought should work.

The constructor for the ExtraItems class is

```
public ExtraItem(int inGuestNum, String inItemType, double inCost)
{
    guestNum = inGuestNum;
    itemType = inItemType;
    cost = inCost;
}
```

Please can I have some assistance? I have attached the full txt file below

1#Mr G Ferreira#Phone#7.05

2#Mrs L Honeywell#Drinks#71.95

3#Ms I Mendes#Kitchen#39.95

1#Mr G Ferreira#Kitchen#23.95

1#Mr G Ferreira#Drinks#7.15

4#Mr B Khoza#Taxi#127.25

5#Mrs I Freulich#Security#31.95

5#Mrs I Freulich#Internet#7.95

6#Mr J Kowalsky#Phone#18.30

Comment: Perhaps just store the data in variables, and then use only the appropriate variables in the constructor, rather than just putting the scanner methods into the constructor itself. I know this isn't an elegant solution, but if it works...

Comment: I tried a similar thing where I added a parameter for the ExtraItems constructor for the guest name and never used it, but I was hoping for a more elegant approach that I can apply in different situations.

Comment: you can do a string split and then use the variables that you want from the split array.